# How React Dom update works in comparison to Vanilla JS update approach

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I am a beginner in React although have worked on multiple JS frameworks like Angular. I was going through their tutorial and got stuck at a concept mentioned at below URL.

https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html

It says -

> "React DOM compares the element and its children to the previous one,
>   and only applies the DOM updates necessary to bring the DOM to the
>   desired state."

They have demonstrated it through a clock example

[image]

I was viewing a stop watch demo at following URL written in Vanilla JavaScript.
When I inspect the DOM I see similar behavior of DOM update.

[Stop Watch @ Codepen](https://codepen.io/y2454liu/pen/BqeRvm?page=1&)

[image]

I don't understand what does React do differently as highlighted by them in their child element rendering concept.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

```js
var timing = false;
var interval;
var time = 0;
var count = document.getElementById("time");
var s = document.getElementById("s");
var r = document.getElementById("r");
var t = document.getElementById("t");
var past = document.getElementById("past");


function startstop(){
    if(!timing) {
        interval = setInterval(function () {
            time += 0.01;
            count.innerHTML = time.toFixed(2).toString();
        }, 10);
        timing = true;
    } else {
        clearInterval(interval);
        timing = false;
    }
}

function reset(){
    clearInterval(interval);
    time = 0;
    count.innerHTML = "0";
    timing = false;
    past.innerHTML = "";
}

function record(){
    var node = document.createElement("li");
    var textnode=document.createTextNode(count.innerHTML);
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    past.appendChild(node);
}

s.addEventListener("click",startstop);//not s.addEventListener("click",startstop());
r.addEventListener("click",reset);
t.addEventListener("click",record);

document.addEventListener("keydown",function(event){
  var press = event.key;
  switch (press)
  {
    case "s" :
      startstop()
      break;
    case "r":
      reset()
      break;
    case "t":
      record()
      break;
    default:
      return
  }
});
```

```css
*{
  text-align: center;
  margin:20px 10px;
  color:#C096E6;
}

h1{
  margin-top:50px;
}

#time{
  font-size:40px;  
}

button{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color:#ffffff;
  background-color: #C096E6;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border:none;
  outline:none;
  &:hover{
    color: #C096E6;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #C096E6;
  }
}

ul{
  margin-left: -20px;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Game</title>

</head>
<body>
  <h1>Stopwatch Demo</h1>
  <p id="time">0</p>

  <button id="s">Start/Stop</button>
  <button id="r">Reset</button>
  <button id="t">Record Time</button>

  <p>Past Times</p>
  <ul id="past"></ul>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's obvious that eventually any React code results to vanilla JS, so it makes no sense to compare them from this POV.

Comment: I _think_ what they're trying to demonstrate is that only the text nodes which needs to change are changing, so, in their example, the `"It is"` part doesn't get updated

Comment: ...just like it makes no sense to compare library X with vanilla JS. The main reason why people choose any library is its convenience from some aspect of development, which vanilla JS can't offer by definition.

Comment: I've got same question, did you find answer? @Manish